Service of Process for Request for Default Entry and Motion for Default Judgement in Federal District Court
This question revolves around a case against US and its agencies or their directors in their official capacity. Moreover the claims in the case are based on Mandamus and APA. The other party (US government) has 60 days to give a response. When does the 60 days exactly start, does it start from the date the earliest defendant was served, the last one was served or the time US Attorney's office (or Attorney General) were served?
Now let's say the 60 comes and passes and they fail to even appear in the case. The plaintiff is considering to file a request for Default Entry and subsequently Motion for Default Judgement (According to Rule 55). Now does the Plaintiff need to serve the Defendants (and AG and US attorney's office) with 1) Request for Default Entry 2) Motion for Default Judgement after filing them and then file the proof of service? (Just like Summons according to Rule 4)? Note that since the other party has not appeared they won't receive NEF through ECF. (I believe all Motions need to get served but not sure about Request for Default Entry)

@dalem How does this "clearly ask for specific legal advice"? It seems sufficiently generic to me.

@bdb484 because it’s asking what is the specific civil procedure for cases in Federal court. Advising on specifics of procedure is legal advice.

Weird interpretation.
